# Nested items are not grouped correctly

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following data structure. Every `lot` have number. And can have multiple objects inside. Every object know it's parent lot number.

So data look like:

```
lots
  lot 
     object 
     object
   lot 
     object
     object
     object
```

I wrote next SQL:

```
SELECT
          json_build_object(
          'purchaseNumber', n."purchaseNumber",
          'responsibleOrg_inn', "responsibleOrg_inn",
          'docPublishDate', "docPublishDate",
          'docPublishDate', "docPublishDate",
          'responsibleOrg_kpp', "responsibleOrg_kpp",
          'responsibleOrg_regNum', "responsibleOrg_regNum",
          'responsibleOrg_fullName', "responsibleOrg_fullName",
          'responsibleOrg_postAddress', "responsibleOrg_postAddress",
          'responsibleOrg_factAddress', "responsibleOrg_factAddress",
          'contactPerson_lastName',"contactPerson_lastName",
          'contactPerson_firstName', "contactPerson_firstName",
          'contactPerson_middleName', "contactPerson_middleName",
          'responsibleInfo_contactEMail', "responsibleInfo_contactEMail",
          'responsibleInfo_contactPhone', "responsibleInfo_contactPhone",

           'customers', json_agg(DISTINCT jsonb_build_object(
                        'customer_regNum', c."customer_regNum",
                        'customer_fullName', c."customer_fullName")
            ),              

            'lots', json_agg(
              json_build_object(
                  'lotNumber', l."lotNumber",
                   'currency_code', l."currency_code",
                    'contractGuarantee_amount', l."contractGuarantee_amount",
                    'KBKCode', l."KBKCode",
          
            'objects', json_build_array( 
            jsonb_build_object(
                          'OKPD_code', o."OKPD_code",
                           'OKPD_name', o."OKPD_name",
                          'price', o."price"
            )
                  )
              )
            )
    )
          FROM notifications n

          left JOIN lots l ON l."purchaseNumber" = n."purchaseNumber"
          left JOIN objects o ON o."purchaseNumber" = n."purchaseNumber" 
          left JOIN customers c ON c."purchaseNumber" = n."purchaseNumber"
      
          WHERE n."purchaseNumber" = '0376200015021000029'

       AND l."lotNumber" = o."lotNumber"
      AND c."lotNumber"::int = l."lotNumber"
          
          GROUP  BY 
          
        n."purchaseNumber",
        "responsibleOrg_inn",
        "docPublishDate",
        "docPublishDate",
        "responsibleOrg_inn",
        "responsibleOrg_kpp",
        "responsibleOrg_regNum",
        "responsibleOrg_fullName",
        "responsibleOrg_postAddress",
        "responsibleOrg_factAddress",
        "contactPerson_lastName",
        "contactPerson_lastName",
        "contactPerson_firstName",
        "contactPerson_middleName",
        "responsibleInfo_contactEMail",
        "responsibleInfo_contactPhone",
        "responsibleRole",
        "placingWay_code",
        etp_code,
        etp_name,
        etp_url,
        is_canceled,
        "procedureInfo_collecting_startDate",
        "procedureInfo_collecting_endDate",
        region,
        "placingWay_name",
        "isGOZ",
        c."customer_fullName",
        c."customer_regNum",
        n."lotMaxPrice"
```

But this request is doing wrong grouping. I am getting result as if:

```
lot 
 object
lot
 object
lot 
 object
....
```

my result:

```
{
    "purchaseNumber": "0376200015021000029",
    "responsibleOrg_inn": "0105025330",
    "docPublishDate": "2021-07-08T13:57:28.554+00:00",
    "responsibleOrg_kpp": "010501001",
    "responsibleOrg_regNum": "03762000150",
    "responsibleOrg_fullName": "Organization Name",
    "responsibleOrg_postAddress": "Some text",
    "responsibleOrg_factAddress": "address",
    "contactPerson_lastName": "Парфенова",
    "contactPerson_firstName": "Инна",
    "contactPerson_middleName": "Назаровна",
    "responsibleInfo_contactEMail": "mail",
    "responsibleInfo_contactPhone": "8-8772-521246",
    "customers": [{
            "customer_regNum": "03762000150",
            "customer_fullName": "Some text"
        }
    ],
    "lots": [{
            "lotNumber": 0,
            "currency_code": null,
            "contractGuarantee_amount": null,
            "KBKCode": null,
            "objects": [{
                    "price": 25.5,
                    "OKPD_code": "22.19.60.119-00000004",
                    "OKPD_name": "aaaaaaaaaa"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "lotNumber": 0,
            "currency_code": null,
            "contractGuarantee_amount": null,
            "KBKCode": null,
            "objects": [{
                    "price": 28.5,
                    "OKPD_code": "22.19.60.113-00000002",
                    "OKPD_name": "bbbbbbbbbb"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "lotNumber": 0,
            "currency_code": null,
            "contractGuarantee_amount": null,
            "KBKCode": null,
            "objects": [{
                    "price": 28.5,
                    "OKPD_code": "22.19.60.113-00000002",
                    "OKPD_name": "cccccccccc"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "lotNumber": 0,
            "currency_code": null,
            "contractGuarantee_amount": null,
            "KBKCode": null,
            "objects": [{
                    "price": 19,
                    "OKPD_code": "22.19.60.119-00000003",
                    "OKPD_name": "dddddddddd"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "lotNumber": 0,
            "currency_code": null,
            "contractGuarantee_amount": null,
            "KBKCode": null,
            "objects": [{
                    "price": 25.5,
                    "OKPD_code": "22.19.60.119-00000004",
                    "OKPD_name": "eeeeeeeeee"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "lotNumber": 0,
            "currency_code": null,
            "contractGuarantee_amount": null,
            "KBKCode": null,
            "objects": [{
                    "price": 15,
                    "OKPD_code": "22.19.60.119-00000010",
                    "OKPD_name": "ffffffffff"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "lotNumber": 0,
            "currency_code": null,
            "contractGuarantee_amount": null,
            "KBKCode": null,
            "objects": [{
                    "price": 15,
                    "OKPD_code": "22.19.60.119-00000010",
                    "OKPD_name": "gggggggggg"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "lotNumber": 0,
            "currency_code": null,
            "contractGuarantee_amount": null,
            "KBKCode": null,
            "objects": [{
                    "price": 24.5,
                    "OKPD_code": "22.19.60.119-00000008",
                    "OKPD_name": "hhhhhhhhhh"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "lotNumber": 0,
            "currency_code": null,
            "contractGuarantee_amount": null,
            "KBKCode": null,
            "objects": [{
                    "price": 24.5,
                    "OKPD_code": "22.19.60.119-00000008",
                    "OKPD_name": "jjjjjjjjjj"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I placed live-db here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4qGbsYmA6ynCB9n4uR2BF3/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by step aggregation, simplified a bit

```
SELECT n."purchaseNumber", 
       jsonb_build_object(
           'purchaseNumber', n."purchaseNumber",
           'lots',      json_agg(l.lots),
           'customers', json_agg(DISTINCT
              jsonb_build_object(
                 'customer_regNum', c."customer_regNum",
                 'customer_fullName', c."customer_fullName")
                )            
   ) pjson  
  FROM notifications n
  LEFT JOIN (             
      select l."purchaseNumber", 
         jsonb_build_object(
           'lot' , l."lotNumber",
           'objects', json_agg(
                jsonb_build_object(
                  'OKPD_code', o."OKPD_code",
                  'OKPD_name', o."OKPD_name",
                  'price', o."price")
               ) 
          ) lots
      from lots l  
      left join objects o on l."lotNumber" = o."lotNumber"
      group by l."purchaseNumber", l."lotNumber"
    )  l ON l."purchaseNumber" = n."purchaseNumber" 
    LEFT JOIN customers c ON c."purchaseNumber" = n."purchaseNumber"
    WHERE n."purchaseNumber" = '0376200015021000029'         
    GROUP BY n."purchaseNumber"
```

Returns

```
{
    "lots": [
        {
            "lot": 0,
            "objects": [
                {
                    "price": 25.5,
                    "OKPD_code": "22.19.60.119-00000004",
                    "OKPD_name": "aaaaaaaaaa"
                },
                {
                    "price": 28.5,
                    "OKPD_code": "22.19.60.113-00000002",
                    "OKPD_name": "bbbbbbbbbb"
                },
                {
                    "price": 28.5,
                    "OKPD_code": "22.19.60.113-00000002",
                    "OKPD_name": "cccccccccc"
                },
                {
                    "price": 19,
                    "OKPD_code": "22.19.60.119-00000003",
                    "OKPD_name": "dddddddddd"
                },
                {
                    "price": 25.5,
                    "OKPD_code": "22.19.60.119-00000004",
                    "OKPD_name": "eeeeeeeeee"
                },
                {
                    "price": 15,
                    "OKPD_code": "22.19.60.119-00000010",
                    "OKPD_name": "ffffffffff"
                },
                {
                    "price": 15,
                    "OKPD_code": "22.19.60.119-00000010",
                    "OKPD_name": "gggggggggg"
                },
                {
                    "price": 24.5,
                    "OKPD_code": "22.19.60.119-00000008",
                    "OKPD_name": "hhhhhhhhhh"
                },
                {
                    "price": 24.5,
                    "OKPD_code": "22.19.60.119-00000008",
                    "OKPD_name": "jjjjjjjjjj"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "customers": [
        {
            "customer_regNum": "03762000150",
            "customer_fullName": "ГОСУДАРСТВЕННОЕ БЮДЖЕТНОЕ УЧРЕЖДЕНИЕ ЗДРАВООХРАНЕНИЯ РЕСПУБЛИКИ АДЫГЕЯ \"МАЙКОПСКАЯ ГОРОДСКАЯ КЛИНИЧЕСКАЯ БОЛЬНИЦА\""
        }
    ],
    "purchaseNumber": "0376200015021000029"
}
```

Comment: what about memory usage? I have very big tables (50+ millions rows in each). And SQL Manager show that that is not enough memory to complete request.

Comment: Try to add `and l."purchaseNumber" = '0376200015021000029'` to  `left join objects o on l."lotNumber" = o."lotNumber"`  Also proper indexes would help. If it doesn't help, ask another question on performance tuning.